# Async UDFs with range parameter in Excel DNA causes error on full page calculation

Tags: c#, excel-dna

The following function works fine when you type in an individual cell and hit enter, the result is as expected.

When the formula is pasted to a number of cells and the sheet is recalced the function mostly (exception is a cell or two maybe populated with the expected value) returns a #value error

```
    [ExcelFunction(Name = "GetRate", IsThreadSafe = true)]
    public static void  GetRate(
        [ExcelArgument("Range containing quantity and rate", AllowReference = false)] object[,] valueRange,
        ExcelAsyncHandle asyncHandle)
    {

                var rate = 0.123456789m;

                asyncHandle.SetResult(rate);
    }
```

No exception is thrown when debugging

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce this behavior using the code you posted, running on Excel 2016 64-bit. Do you have any example project that shows this behavior on a specific Excel version?

[image: example]

[image: code]

[image: office version]

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me a few times already, somewhat intermittently when developing a function while debugging with hot module reloading. When you change the function metadata significantly, you need to restart Excel so it can re-read the metadata file and parse the new function specs.

Check that the JSON metadata is adding `"dimensionality": "matrix"` to your function parameters and that Excel is parsing the file successfully and maybe try again. In my case, the issue would eventually go away.